# Not null fields for ActiveAttr

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm having issues enforcing a field to not be nil within `ActiveAttr::Model`.

Is there an elegant way of enforcing this constraint within the model instead of defining it in the controller? Or am I testing incorrectly for the scenario?

Model:

```
class Message
  include ActiveAttr::Model

  attribute :name, :presence => true, :allow_nil => false, :allow_blank => false
  attribute :email, :presence => true
  attribute :content, :presence => true

  validates_format_of :email, :with => /^[-a-z0-9_+\.]+\@([-a-z0-9]+\.)+[a-z0-9]{2,4}$/i
  validates_length_of :content, :maximum => 500
end
```

RSpec:

```
module MessageSpecHelper
  def valid_message_attributes
    {
       :name => "Walter White",
       :email => "walter@hailtheking.com",
       :content => "I am the one who knocks"
   }
  end
end

it "should have error on name (alternate with nil)" do 
  @message.attributes = valid_message_attributes.except(:name => nil)
  @message.should have(1).error_on(:name)
end
```

Comment: Don't you want: `@message.attributes = valid_message_attributes.except(:name)` instead?

Comment: That test passes fine. This is an alternate version with an explicit 'nil'